# JavaScript if/else shorthand

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JS and I realize that the following might be some sort of shorthand notation, but I have not seen something like this before and therefore am not sure what this statement is saying. Can someone please explain it to me?

```
if ($scope.userInformationData) {
    $scope.callReport.Created_In_S1_App__c = ($scope.userInformationData.media == 'SALESFORCE1' ? true : false);
} else {
    $scope.callReport.Created_In_S1_App__c = true;
}
```

Having trouble understanding this if/else block (with the ? : notation)
Thanks for the help and I appreciate the explanation

Comment: if condition ? when_True : when_false;

`var canDrink = person.Age < 18 ? false : true;`

Comment: Your book should explain this.

Comment: Ternary operator are present in some language such as Java, C (family) etc... Here is some info on it : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#JavaScript

Comment: The code you've supplied is a very poor example of its usage, to be honest, as it's trying to check a Boolean value for true or false, then set another value to true or false based on that value, which is complete redundancy.

This...

    `$scope.callReport.Created_In_S1_App__c = ($scope.userInformationData.media == 'SALESFORCE1' ? true : false);`

... should simply be...

    `$scope.callReport.Created_In_S1_App__c = $scope.userInformationData.media == 'SALESFORCE1';`

Answer (score 0):

You coud use the ternary operator [`?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> The **conditional (ternary) operator** is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the **[`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)** statement.

```
$scope.callReport.Created_In_S1_App__c = $scope.userInformationData ?
    $scope.userInformationData.media == 'SALESFORCE1' :
    true;
```